# Is a deforming force tension acting on the Moon while orbiting Earth?

Tags: gravity, astrophysics, orbital-motion, centripetal-force, centrifugal-force

As the Moon shows only one face to the Earth can this statement be correct:As a point mass closest to Earth should orbit Earth faster than the most distant point regarding Earth according to the Law of orbital motion in gravitational field and as it is not the fact with the Moon as the the distant point is faster than the closest point is the most distant point trying to go in a greater orbit while the closest points wants to go to a shorter orbit resulting in a tension trying to stretch the Moon to a form of a ellipsoid?

Comment: Sure.  The mismatch between orbital speed and actual speed in a solid body like the Moon or the Earth is the origin of tidal forces.  But you've got the speed difference upside down: the most distant point moves faster than the closest point (the length of its path is greater, but the path is traversed in the same amount of time).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, a satellite is deformed by the gravity of its primary. More precisely, this deformation is due to  the tidal effects caused by the difference in the gravitational attraction of the primary from one side of the satellite to the other. The effect is greater the larger the satellite and the closer the satellite is to the primary. [Tidal forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_force) have several effects on satellites:

1. They can cause [tidal heating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_heating) of the satellite.
2. The rotational period of the satellite tends to become synchronised
   with its orbital period, an effect called [tidal locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_locking).
3. A satellite that orbits too close to its primary can be pulled apart
   by tidal forces - see [Roche limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roche_limit).

Since planets can be considered to be satellites of their sun, the same effects apply to a planet that orbits close to its sun. In our solar system the planet [Mercury](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercury_(planet)) has a 3:2 spin-orbit resonance caused by tidal locking, and is thought to have a molten core (and hence a magnetic field) due to tidal heating.